# Foundation Dropdowns In Angular.JS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, zurb-foundation

I'm working on a project based in Foundation and now we're thinking we'd like to move it into angular.js but unfortunately angular is handling the clicks so all of my modals and dropdowns don't work.  what's the best way of handling these?

Comment: please provide some of the code of what you have so far?

Comment: ??? My problem isn't syntax but rather how to get two code bases to work together.  You sure you read my question?

Comment: Duplicate of [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14657282/zrub-foundation-dropdown-buttons-break-inside-angular-partial) which has an answer

Answer (score 3):

I'd recommend using [angular-ui-foundation](https://github.com/mhayes/angular-ui-foundation) for all the directives they provide !

Comment: that library is incomplete

Comment: There are several packages out there, and adding directives yourself is really that easy, *snap*

Comment: you dont have to tell me, i use foundation as well and create my own custom directives for what i need